# Ecommerce website flowchart

Tags: e-commerce, ux-designer, flowcharts

I'm working on creating a flowchart for an e-commerce website the task a bit complicated because of many cases and scenarios I need to take into consideration.

can you provide a link for a real e-commerce company flowchart ?

Comment: could you be more specific? when you say 'e-commerce company flowchart' do you mean something like the company's internal structure? or the user flow?

Answer (score -1):

Try googling this:

"e commerce company structure", then tap the images tab button.

[image]